# How can I remove quotes from an NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to remove quotes from something like:

"Hello"

so that the string is just:

Hello

Comment: what does this even have to do with Xcode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out Apple's docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/

You probably want:

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:
```

Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a target string in the receiver are replaced by another given string.

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

So, something like this should work:

```
newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```

Comment: You're missing `withString` in the final example.

Comment: stringByReplacing will also change "Hell"o" into Hello, which isn't the desired behavior. Should be using stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet

Comment: Right; it wasn't clear from the question what the actual input requirements are, or if that is a possible input.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer From your error message it looks like you are trying to call on an array instead of a string.

Answer (score 3):

I only wanted to remove the first quote and the last quote, not the quotes within the string so here's what I did:

```
challengeKey = @"\"I want to \"remove\" the quotes.\"";
challengeKey = [challengeKey substringFromIndex:1];
challengeKey = [challengeKey substringToIndex:[challengeKey length] - 1];
```

Hope this helps others looking for the same thing.  NSLog and you'll get this output:

```
I want to "remove" the quotes.
```

Comment: you've got a mistake there it should be [challengeKey length] - 1, not 2