# How to remove ("") double quotes char in NSString in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove quotes from an NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121478/how-can-i-remove-quotes-from-an-nsstring)

Currently i am working in iphone application, Here i am using NSXmlparser to parse xml file, the values comes city name is "Melbourne" in NSString, i want to remove left and right double quotes, please any one help these

Thanks

Here i tried:

```
myString = @"Melbourne";
NSString *Replace =[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""" withString:@""];
```

Comment: Ivor's suggestion should work but note that your code is a bad example since `myString` does **not** contain any double quotes in the first place.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should do it:

```
[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```